# After stopping the websphere server, canoot start it again unless i restart the computer

Tags: java, websphere

I can start the web sphere server normally at the start of the computer. If I want to restart or publish the server, it works perfectly fine. However, once I stopped the server, I could not start it again no matter how I try. I have to restart the computer to make it working again. The error message says that

```
Starting websphere application server classic v8.5 at localhost has encountered a problem. Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already started.
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how to solve that

Comment: is your server instance listed as a windows service?

Comment: @Sampada how can i check that?

Comment: Go to services (type services.msc) in the Run menu (Windows +r key). Check the list of services to see if there is one for IBM web sphere 8.5

Comment: yes it is still listing in there

Comment: now, i have stopped the services and still try to start, it doesn't work

Comment: then most probably your jvm is crashing in each server start. check the memory settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112760/discussion-between-sampada-and-chit-khine).

Comment: check your startServer.log

Comment: Probably your server is failing to stop and is still running. Check in Task Manager if the java process is stopped. You probably have wrong credentials used during stop. Check the SystemOut.log.

Comment: @Sampada which chat would u like to discuss about bro? I checked the log and there was nothing in it. It just says 
Starting websphere application server classic v8.5 at localhost has encountered a problem. Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already started.

Comment: by java process do u mean java.exe? @Gas

Comment: I found 4 nodes in my services, and I tried starting them from the services and the server started back. But it seems like, it is running on several nodes since I have to start at least 3 from 4 of them to start my server. That is very interesting or somethings even all of them.

Comment: Yes, java.exe. If you have multiple services, attached their names to your question, as you may have the Network Deployment edition. In that case you should be able to restart server via web admin console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stopping the server you should try to use the stopServer(node/manager/etc).sh

Now as it was mentioned before in the comments, if you are seeing that error it means that there are still some other WebSphere process running. Check the process by going into the Task Manager -> Processes (Check the Box for "Show processes for all users").

Usually the WAS process are named java and WASService.exe. The java process for dmgr is usually 200,000K or more, Node Agent and Servers might be smaller depending on your env. The WASService.exe is much smaller than the java.exe one.  Now you could kill these processes and that should help. In addition to that you can go to the Services section of the task manager and you can review the ones known as IBMWASXXServices and these can also be stopped (I think someone else suggested this as well).

Finally if you keep struggling with this issue, it might be good to open a PMR with IBM and you will be helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your server log location, delete the pid file before starting it. Sometimes WebSphere does not delete that file when you stop the Server.